# How to call public method of sibling component LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, communication

DO i need to use message Channel to call public method of sibling components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have 2 child sibling components and an event on child-component-1 needs to call the child-component-2's method, then do the following:

- dispatch a custom event from child-component-1's event handler method
- define a handler/ listener for this custom event on the parent component's HTML.
- call the child-component-2's public method from parent component's JS handler.

Otherwise, if you have method that implements functionality useful for 2 top level sibling components, you should create a shared JS module as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_share_code) and have a method on each component that calls this shared JS code.

**Note:**

- Public methods in LWC are accessible **only** within the containment hierarchy (*i.e., only the parent or owner components can call a public method on the child component*).
- Lightning Message Service is used to communicate across DOM over lightning message channel using lightning message service functions (i.e., it doesn't really care about whether the sibling components are LWC or Aura or VF). As long as a component has subscribed to a particular channel (using the lightning message service function `subscribe`), the defined listener will respond. And, this listener has to be defined within the lwc or in a shared JS module (that's imported into the lwc).

Comment: Hi @arut, i have to call a method of child1 component from child2 component's button. With the share JS code, i wouldn't be able to achieve this.

Comment: In that case, you can dispatch a custom event from the child2 and have the parent call the method on child1. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanku so much.. I understood the approach.

Comment: Hi @arut , In my case, I have some rendering condition on child1 and  it's doesn't satisfy the rendering condition, when i click button on child2. Child1 is not visible that's y i am not able to call the public method.

Comment: Can the child1 be made visible on click on child2's button? If yes, then before dispatching custom event (or in the parent handler method), you can toggle the field that controls the visibility of child1. Otherwise, shared JS code would be the apt one.  BTW, other than this public method having some functional logic, does it cause any visible change on the page or at component level? In other words, does this method have to be on child1 or can it be placed in the shared code that both the components can access?

Comment: Hi @arut, That's impacting the visibility, that's why i changed the relationship from sibiling to parent and child.  Now child2 is child of child1. It's giving more freedom for communication. Thanku for all help.